# angularFire route resolution

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase

I'd like to have my `angularFire` collection resolve on route loading. Something like:

```
App.config ($routeProvider, angularFireProvider) ->
  $routeProvider.when '/test',
    templateUrl: 'views/test.html'
    controller: 'TestCtrl'
    resolve: angularFireProvider.resolve 'testItems'
```

Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure why you want the collection to resolve on route loading, as opposed to in the controller - could you elaborate? For example, the following would work too:

```js
App.config ($routeProvider, angularFireProvider) ->
  $routeProvider.when '/test',
  controller: 'TestCtrl'

function TestCtrl($scope, angularFire) {
  angularFire("https://<example>.firebaseio.com", $scope, "collection").
    then(function() {
      // The collection has been resolved and available in $scope.collection
    });
}
```

Is it mainly a matter syntactic convenience or am I missing functionality you want in the above?

Update: For the value to be resolved before the `$routeChangeSuccess` event is fired:

```js
 App.config(['$routeProvider', 'angularFire', function($routeProvider, angularFire) {
   $routeProvider.when("/test", {
     templateUrl: 'views/test.html'
     controller: 'TestCtrl',
     resolve: {collection: angularFire("https://<example>.firebaseio.com")}
   });
 }]);

 function TestCtrl(collection) {
   // collection has already been resolved to its value.
 }
```

Comment: In this method `$routeChangeSuccess` will be emitted before the `angularFire` resources are resolved, right?

Comment: You're right - if you want the value to be resolved before the event Fires, you can just simply move the call to `angularFire` into your resolve property, since it returns a promise. I'll edit the answer to provide a code snippet.

Comment: Anant, on the off chance you may see this, I'm trying to use the resolve functionality but it states that angularFire is an unknown provider (on a related note is angularFireCollection not more appropriate in this instance owing to not requiring a scope?). aF and aFC work fine elsewhere in my code but is there perhaps something I'm missing in using it with config and resolve?